# Convert dollars to cents in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert $3.77 (USD) to cents as follows:

```
const number = "3.77"
const separe = number.replace(".", "")
```

Is that the correct way to convert USD to cents? because I have seen some reports with different code and not which one is correct, any ideas?

Comment: `const separe = Number(number) ? Number(number * 100).`

Comment: Yours is also correct.

Comment: Depends on the formatting expected. Say I had `0.02`, would they want `002`? Or should it be `2`?

Comment: yes, it should be 002, And if it is an integer value, how would it be? for example $7

Comment: A US dollar is equal to 100 US cents. Use that knowledge to convert the number of dollars to the number of cents.

Comment: You'll need to know the possible set of inputs the user is allowed to make and adjust what you do. Clearly just taking the period away isn't going to work for just the string `"7"`. But the user could even do: `"75¢"`. If it's always `#.##` then your solution will work, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 10):

Be careful when doing arithmetic calculation in JavaScript. Especially if you are dealing with floating point.

Consider this case:

```
+19.99 * 100 // 1998.9999999999998
19.99 * 100 // 1998.9999999999998
parseFloat(19.99) * 100 // 1998.9999999999998
```

I know, right?! So I made this simple helper to help you out:

```
const toCent = amount => {
  const str = amount.toString()
  const int = str.split('.')

  return Number(amount.toFixed(2).replace('.', '').padEnd(int.length === 1 ? 3 : 4, '0'))
}
```

Result:

```
toCent(19.99) // 1999
toCent(19.9) // 1990
toCent(1.9) // 190
toCent(1999.99) // 199999
```

I haven't tested it yet thoroughly. Please don't copy paste my solution, at least you do your own test.

Comment: there is small bug - `const int = str.split('.')` instead of `const [int] = str.split('.')`

Comment: Finally an answer that considers the IEEE floating point arithmetic. Thanks

Comment: this seems too complicated, why not the toFixed(0)?

Comment: This just works :)

Answer (score 6):

This will do it with any value.

```
export function toCents(aValue){
  return Math.round((Math.abs(aValue) / 100) * 10000);
}
```

Comment: `toCents(17.49)  // 1748`

Comment: @OrionHall just updated the function.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are doing it now works, but isn't ideal. I have [benchmarked](https://jsben.ch/Sp0yl) your answer vs the answers from the comments and here are the results.

**Winner:**

```
const result = (parseFloat(number) * 100).toString();
```

**Second Place (~99% of Winner):**

```
const result = (Number(number) * 100).toString();
```

**Third Place (~96% of Winner):**

```
const result = (+number * 100).toString();
```

**Fourth Place (~80% of Winner):**

```
const result = number.replace(".", "");
```

As noted, your method will not work when the string does not match `/\d\.\d\d/` however the other methods will work.

<sup><sub>Tested on Safari 14</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(x * 100)` seems pretty safe because it will round to the nearest integer. The better options are:

1. Always represent your amounts in cents (i.e. whole numbers) and divide into dollars when needed
2. Use a library (such as decimal.js or Big.js)

The implementations in the above two libraries are super complex ([here](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/blob/3dcadc7351eace5dd61a48ad5bfea8c1dd388ec2/decimal.js#L1873), [here](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/blob/master/big.js#L838)).